# Display statistics in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a working query for statistics. It is output to datagridview. Next, I want to arrange the display of statistics by a graph. But the graph is not displayed.
[here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkl2i.png)

here is my code:

```
void FillChartAnimalsStat()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Anesia;Initial Catalog=WEP_Clinic_Db;Integrated Security=True");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select kind_definition, count(*) as amount" +
                "\r\nfrom Kinds_of_animals inner join Patients on Kinds_of_animals.kind_id = Patients.kind_id " +
                "\r\ninner join Visits on Patients.patient_id = Visits.patient_id group by Kinds_of_animals.kind_definition order by amount desc", con);
        da.Fill(dt);
        chart1.Series["Statistics"].XValueMember = "kind_definition";
        chart1.Series["Statistics"].YValueMembers = "amount";
        chart1.Titles.Add("Види тварин на прийомах за частотою їх розподілу");

    }
```

I did the video tutorial, repeated everything in exactly the same way, but there is no result. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you ever setting the `DataSource` of your Chart?

Comment: As @Jimi pointed out, your SqlConnection, DataTable and SqlDataAdapter are being created at runtime, and nowhere in your code do you set the DataSource of the Chart. How is the Chart supposed to know where to get its contents?

Comment: How is the chart created? By code or in the designer? If by code, did you add all necessary elements, including a chartarea? I also see no data binding call. [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+databinding)

Comment: @Jimi Exactly, I forgot to add DataSource. Now everything works, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Problem found - it was necessary to add DataSource